# Apache <Location> tag for couple of options

Tags: configuration, apache2

I want to set couple of `Location` tags in my Apache config. For instance: `/image`, `/file`, `/audio` and to pass it to `localhost:port/path`. Right now I'm using this for `/image`:

```
 <Location /image>
        RewriteEngine  on
        Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass "http://localhost:PORT/image"
        ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:PORT/image"
    </Location>
```

Do I have to write this piece of code for every param? Or there is any shortcut for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <Location /image>
>    RewriteEngine  on
>    Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
>    AllowOverride All
>    ProxyPreserveHost On
>    ProxyPass "http://localhost:PORT/image"
>    ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:PORT/image"
> </Location>
> ```
>
> Do I have to write this piece of code for every param?

No. The `RewriteEngine` directive doesn't do anything there and neither the `Options` nor the `AllowOverride` directives make any sense when you don't map to resources on the local file system. Those options are controlled and need to be set by the "remote" webserver that you are forwarding the requests to with the `ProxyPass` directive.

Since those directives  are useless, then you don't need the Location bracket either to set them and can use the inline [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) syntax that is recommended anyway.

That reduces your syntax to only the necessary lines:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass "/image" "http://localhost:PORT/image"
ProxyPassReverse "/image" "http://localhost:PORT/image"

ProxyPass "/file" "http://localhost:PORT/file"
ProxyPassReverse "/file" "http://localhost:PORT/file"
```

---

Apache httpd does offer the [`Include`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include) directive to maintain a single configuration snippet with settings that you want to include  verbatim in different places, VirtualHost, Location, Directory blocks without copying the same lines time after time.